# '100' is a magic number

Tags: java, constants

Magic numbers are bad... I totally agree. But there's one magic number I find hard to fix:

> **'100' is a magic number.**

Consider this code:

```
public double getPercent(double rate) {
    return rate * 100;
}

public double getRate(double percent) {
    return percent / 100;
}
```

SonarQube will raise 2 violations, one for each use of 100. I could replace 100 with a constant variable, but what would be a good name for it? Is that really a good idea? If somebody ever changes its value that will be a disaster. I could also just add `// NOSONAR` to all the lines that use 100.

What is the best practice for dealing with the magic number 100?

---

**UPDATE**

From the answers, the most useful bit for me was this:

> **Practical Magic Number rule**: A literal is a not a magic number if the most meaningful variable name for it is the same as the spoken name of the literal.

So by this logic, 100 is NOT a magic number.

However, to make the violation go away, I decided to replace the 100 with a constant:

```
public static final double HUNDRED = 100;  // change it and I'll kill you
```

In my real project there are many lines using 100, and if I put `// NOSONAR` on all those lines that might cover up other potential problems that other developers might inadvertently add later.

Not sure if there will be any real benefits using this constant. A small one may be that when I do `git grep 100` I see a lot of matches from resource files in the project, while `git grep HUNDRED` turns up just the the Java code that uses this.

Comment: I've written a [rant on stupid linters](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/223625/60357) over on programmers. Adding a named constant for the `100` here would just be obfuscation. However, I feel you aren't looking for a code review of that very small snippet, but for best practices regarding such cases, which unfortunately is an opinion-based question.

Comment: What is adding insult to injury is the underlying reason: you shouldn't have magic numbers but meaningful identifiers. _But that's exactly why there is a meaningful identifier on the previous line_: `getPercent` !

Comment: Well, it will allow you to more easily change it if the percentage of 1 ever changes... ;)

Comment: It’s not your fault that real life did not adhere to best practice and made 100 a magic number.

Comment: You could name it PERCENT_TO_RATE_RATIO = 100

Comment: `HUNDRED` is absolutely as useless as `100`, and potentially even more harmful since someone could ignore your comment and change it. If anything it proves that it matches the "practical magic number rule" and shouldn't be a variable, final or not.

Comment: _The benefit of using the constant instead of the value 100 is that I can easily lookup usages_ -- What happens if you search for "`100`": do you find other, non-percentage-related places where it's being used? IMO the intent of the "practical" rule was to say that if "HUNDRED" is the best you can do then 100 is valid as a hard-coded number and is not an 'invalid, magic' number.

Comment: Im with Kevin on this one. Using constants as "HUNDRED" or similar doesnt really make them less magic.

Comment: http://www.xkcd.com/1275/

Comment: Similarly, in our code base, someone left `c_chf constant varchar2(3) := 'CHF'`. This stupidity can only be explained for tools such as sonar. Leave the 100 as 100, everybody understands it.

Comment: One advantage of a variable is to have the compiler check for typos. Not very relevant for a hundred, might be more so for a billion. But as other people have been saying, the usual reasons for avoiding magic numbers don't apply here, and things like int THREE = 3; are very silly.

Comment: [Relevant Q&A on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/266717/142319)

Comment: Sonar has an option to flag an issue has a False Positive. This seems most appropriate to situations like these. No editing rules, no preventing analysis on certain lines.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Speaking as a human programmer (i.e. I am not Lint software), your use of "100" there looks fine to me.

Wikipedia has an article (without citations) titled [Accepted limited use of magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Accepted_limited_use_of_magic_numbers): IMO your "100" is in the same category as these other "accepted" magic numbers.

---

[This Wiki describing magic numbers](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MagicNumber) says two things.

Firstly,

> **Practical Magic Number rule**: A literal is a not a magic number if the most meaningful variable name for it is the same as the spoken name of the literal.

That's applicable here: you're looking for a named constant like `HUNDRED` or `CENTUM`.

Secondly, it also suggests loading "magic" numbers (e.g. a "discount rate") from a configuration file:

```
static final double DISCOUNT_PERCENT = getProperty( "sales.discount_percent" );
static final double DISCOUNT_FACTOR = 1 - (DISCOUNT_PERCENT / 100);

// ...

salePrice = DISCOUNT_FACTOR * regularPrice;
```

Note that though this example code carefully loaded `DISCOUNT_PERCENT` from a configuration, the "100" used to calculate the `DISCOUNT_FACTOR` is hard-coded.

---

If you use "100" instead of `HUNDRED`, it's easier for a programmer to understand, and to verify that it's correct.

IMO the only benefit to using `HUNDRED` is to find the several methods which use the same magic number (in your example it's used by `getPercent` and `getRate`).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, 0, 1, 2 don't raise violations in our tools. But 100 does. Maybe you're right and I can consider these false positives.

Comment: @janos then you can do `return rate * 2 * 2 * 5 * 5;`. Much easier since it doesn't contain magic numbers. Much easier to read as well since it's been factorized /s

Comment: I don’t even agree with the “only benefit” you mention: searching for “HUNDRED” is no easier than searching for “100”. 100 is *not* a magic number here and there’s no reason to reduce clarity in order to kowtow to some linter.

Comment: @bdesham Conceivably there are other places where "100" is being used: as an error code, in huffman code tables, in some enum value, in resource files, etc. It _is_ the only benefit that I can think of; but I agree with you that it's not a sufficient benefit to make it worthwhile.

Comment: @WernerCD: Sorry, only 0,1 and 2 are not magic. ITYM `(rate << 2) * (2*2+1) * (2+2+1)`.

Comment: @WernerCD Too complicated! `1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1` ftw.

Comment: My first thought was that surely you shouldn't be converting between rate and percentage in code since you'd use rate for all calculations and percentage only when displaying to the user. Does Java not have any nice number formatting methods that will format a double as a percentage string?

Answer (score 64):

Although `100` should be fine in source-code, I'm surprised nobody has offered the most *readable* alternative yet.  This should be acceptable for both humans and lint-code:

Define your constant `PERCENT=0.01`.

Then, when you need to do a conversion:

```
rate = discount*PERCENT
```

or

```
discount = rate/PERCENT
```

This can completely eliminate your short functions (which are, indeed, trivial).  You could have additional constants `PERMILLE`, `PPM`, `PPB`, etc., and it should be obvious for humans what is happening.

Comment: +100 Or if you *really* must make it clear what the constant means, name it `PER_CENT` as in "per one hundred"--the definition of percent.

Comment: Created an account just to vote this up. This is way better than the other answers.

Comment: very good, but there are some caveats, I believe, with the internal representation... you may need to have one per types of data (float, double float, etc)... 100 (or a constant valued at 100) is safer to use.See: [Java Double value = 0.01 changes to 0.009999999999999787](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408566/java-double-value-0-01-changes-to-0-009999999999999787) or [why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) or [rounding-errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960072/rounding-errors)

Comment: I can't really call this more readable.  In particular, `discount = rate/PERCENT` feels rather contorted.  Without *very* clear names, and perhaps even with, it'd be way too easy to forget whether `PERCENT` is 0.01 or 100.  Perhaps if it were called `ONE_PERCENT` or something, i dunno...but as is, it's more magical than if it were left a "magic number".

Comment: *Sigh*. `discount*0.01` and `rate/0.01` is *not* the same as `discount/100` and `rate*100`. While `100` is exact, `0.01` is not.

Comment: @DavidOngaro Oops, indeed.  But as the context seems to involve money, using Decimal seems prudent.

Comment: @gerrit: I don't see that context in the question. But the accepted answer uses a price calculation as an example, which is surely an anti-example when done with float arithmetic.

Answer (score 27):

Some numbers are called 'magic' because it is unclear where they come from. I think in this particular case, it is clear that 100 originates from the definition of percent. However, if you wish you can define a constant `PERCENTS_IN_UNIT_RATE=100` instead of using it directly.

Violations reported by code analysis tools are really only suggestions and it is okay to disagree with them. If in doubt ask other programmers who work on the same project, or toss a coin and move to the next task! :-)

Comment: I don't think `HUNDRED` is any more readable than 100. Yes, it will satisfy the immediate tool complaints, but you probably use the tool to raise code quality, and as I mentioned it does not do so in my opinion. `MAX_PERCENT` is better but still may raise questions. `PERCENT_MAX` sounds similar to `INT_MAX` and may be slightly better yet. `PERCENTS_IN_UNIT_RATE` is imho most understandable but is also too long. Hence, I'd vote for keeping literal 100.

Comment: `MAX_PERCENT` seems misleading in that it implies that the 100 is just an arbitrary constant that could be changed any time. It would seem to me that outside of dodgy accounting practices, 100 is pretty immutable :-)

Comment: `A100PERCENTS` or `ONE100PERCENTS` or `PERCENTS_100` or `X100PERCENTS` would all work IMO. I like these because they include numeric 100, and also include word *percent*, making both numeric value and context apparent.

Comment: If I buy a goat for $1 and sell it for $8, then I've sold it for 800% of its original price. `MAX_PERCENT` should probably be a constant equal to `DBL_MAX`. Just use 100 and avoid confusion.

Comment: I have no idea where `RATE` in `PERCENTS_PER_UNIT_RATE` came from.  Because you're working on an interest rate?  But that has absolutely no effect on conversion between percentage and scale.  I'd suggest `PERCENT_PER_UNITY` or something like that.

Answer (score 20):

I am on the fence about the 100 being a named constant or not.

I habitually make magic numbers named constants, but not all the time.... it is not unusual for me to have constants called [`HUNDRED` or `MILLION`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/42544/31503). I also regularly have trivial numbers as magic-number constants ....

But, in this case, and what I particularly want to draw attention to, is that your value should be a floating-point, not an integral value.

When you have constants they should be in the most convenient form for users to understand. For example, your value `100` should really be `100.0` which makes the fact that it is a double value obvious.

Comment: When you use a constant called `HUNDRED`, is it `100` or `100.0`?

Comment: @JoonasPulakka I would make it `private static final double HUNDRED = 100.0;`

Comment: Ok, but that's just one possibility. `HUNDRED` could as well be a `BigInteger`, or `BigDecimal`, or `byte`, just to mention a few. With number literals, the type is immediately obvious.

Comment: If you end up dealing with large numbers a lot, i think things like `MILLION` could come in handy just because it could be very easy to mistake 1000000 for 10000000 etc

Comment: If you use `HUNDRED` in lots of places, then, when you need to change it in a subset of these places and try to change the constant... you're messed up. This would be no better than doing something like `sed 's/100/101/g'` for all of your project codebase.

Comment: @DLeh `1_000_000`

Answer (score 15):

Others have already stated why they believe that 100 is an acceptable constant here. This answer shows how you can get Sonar to accept that.

Under `your-sonar-domain/profiles/`, you can edit quality profiles, and the rules in them. The "Magic Number" rule is customisable, you can specify certain numbers for the rule to ignore. Simply specify "100" as a number to ignore.

[image: Change ignoreNumbers to include "100!]

Answer (score 2):

It technically is since both those 100's have the same context.  Similar to me using 32 as a width in several different places.  It depends how nitpicky you want to be.  In this case I might use something like `MAX_PERCENT`.  It does help with readability as well since when I see that I know the calculations have to do with percentages.

Comment: I would be rather amused if I saw code that used `MAX_PERCENT`

Comment: Poor attempt at brevity I guess.  Though being amused by something helps remember it.

Answer (score 1):

If forced to use a symbol, I might call it N100.  That way you can tell what its value is.  A long time ago I saw this done for common constants.  And negative numbers were prefixed with "M".   Why did they do this?  Because the computer instruction set couldn't load numbers in line ("immediate"); they had to be fetched from a memory location.  And the assembler used symbols to refer to those locations.

Answer (score 1):

I think 100 IS a magic number here.

Percentage is vastly used, but also per mille (1/1000) is often used, and basis point (1/10.000) and percent mille (1/100.000) are used enough to have their own name.

I would change your function to `getPerPart(value, part)` and `getFromPart(value, part)`, maybe with a default `getPerPart(value)` and `getFromPart(value)`, which use `DEFAULT_PART_VALUE = 100`.

Also, you may still want to write a `getPercent`, in which case the use of hardcoded 100 is fine.

Comment: You are really going to make functions for multiplication and division? Why not allow your formatter to display numbers how the user wants to see them? You're not going to use these functions in calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Any number that remains unnamed remains a magic number. It's not related common usage as common usage is relative. The problem with it is "when" or "where" to draw a line... when does a number changes its state to non-magic...

2,71828... may not be magic for mathematicians (Euler)

1760 may not be a magic number for anglo saxons (Yards per mile)

10000000 may not be magic for south inhabitant of south asia (crore)

1 may not be magic in the context of multiplication (neutral element)

The relative approach will lead to a discussion that will evolve a local aggreement. And the result to consider a number to be non-magic, will depend on when and where you start the discussion. Unfortunally this discussion has to be lead for each number separately.

The absolute approach is simple an clear: Every number that is not named is a magic number. Discussion over... for all numbers... Of course this is only a (one) definition. But this definition has inherent properties that will make it possible to evaluate it exactly.

So if you want to discuss, go for the relative approach. You will find the discussions never ending. And if you think it is over another number comes along.

Or you go and find a definition that can be used in boolean expressions that will evaluate to true or false.

I go the second way with following definition: Every unnamed number is magic. Even if you practically ignore it the statement stays the same.