# Down with FizzBuzz... LOL

Tags: beginner, fizzbuzz, lolcode

This post is the result of reading through and following the [LOLCODE Specification 1.2](https://github.com/justinmeza/lolcode-spec/blob/master/v1.2/lolcode-spec-v1.2.md) ("smoking the manual", right?), and writing and executing my code on [compileonline.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lolcode_online.php).

My "hello world" was going to be a [fizzbuzz](/questions/tagged/fizzbuzz). I like it because it nicely illustrates the basics of a language - variables, operators, looping, conditionals, and the likes.

As far as naming goes, the specification allows for a wide variety, so I decided to go `PascalCase` all the way, so as to ease up the reading a bit - otherwise the language is *a bit harsh on the eyes*, to say the least.

I'm curious about how idiomatic my code is - this is my very first <s>and probably last</s> [lolcode](/questions/tagged/lolcode) program. Did I overlook language constructs that would help readability? How's naming? Indentation? Any issues?

```
HAI 1.2

    I HAS A Fizz ITZ 3
    I HAS A Buzz ITZ 5

    IM IN YR FrootLoopz UPPIN YR Frootz TIL BOTH SAEM Frootz AN 100 
      BTW Frootz runs 0 through 99

      I HAS A Froot ITZ SUM OF Frootz AN 1
        BTW Froot will run 1 through 100

      BOTH SAEM 0 AN MOD OF Froot AN PRODUKT OF Fizz AN Buzz
      O RLY?
        YA RLY
          Froot R "FizzBuzz"
        NO WAI
          BOTH SAEM 0 AN MOD OF Froot AN Fizz
          O RLY?
            YA RLY
              Froot R "Fizz"
            NO WAI
              BOTH SAEM 0 AN MOD OF Froot AN Buzz
              O RLY?
                YA RLY
                  Froot R "Buzz"
              OIC
          OIC
      OIC

      VISIBLE Froot

    IM OUTTA YR FrootLoopz

    VISIBLE "DOWN WITH FIZZBUZZ LOL"

KTHXBYE
```

Comment: I was expecting `CHEEZE` and `BURGER`, not `FizzBuzz`.

Comment: A serious code review about code written in a joke language? And asking about the idiomaticity of said code? Sometimes I wonder about this place.

Comment: @fluffy I'm starting to wonder too, and we have a [meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2409/is-lolcode-reviewable) about the matter.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I like how you have declared the Fizz and Buzz 'constants'. It makes the code more readable.

The comments are useful too, though, for consistency, the second comment should be changed from:

> ```
> BTW Froot will run 1 through 100
> ```

to

```
BTW Froot runs 1 through 100
```

The idea of generating `Froot` from `Frootz` is also good, because it reduces the computations later in the code.

I only wish you used a better name than `Frootz` because it conflicts with `Froot`. The similarity is.... uncanny.

I would suggest the name `Loopz`:

```
I HAS A Loopz ITZ SUM OF Frootz AN 1
```

This will reduce the ambiguity, and improve the readability and maintainability.

Finally, it is good that you put the `Fizz` modulo check before the `Buzz` check because that improves performance. Many people put buzz first, but that means the modulo-5 check happens, and that fails more often than the modulo-3 check, so people who do the Buzz-loop first tend to do about 20% more conditional checks.

All in all, for a first go, I am very impressed with your result. I can't wait until you implement a [fim++](/questions/tagged/fim%2b%2b) interpreter in [lolcode](/questions/tagged/lolcode). Till then!

Comment: It is oddly appropriate for you to answer this question given your name.

Comment: Tough decision here, I'm giving you the checkmark on this one.. but I'm surprised nobody mentioned that I'm doing 3*5 at every iteration, could have used a `I HAS A FizzBuzz ITZ PRODUKT OF Fizz AN Buzz` outside the loop.

Comment: I had to check and make sure that [tag:fim++] still didn't exist. Whew. Safe for another year.

Comment: @RubberDuck What is fim++?

Comment: @user00001 Dear Princess Celestia... https://esolangs.org/wiki/FiM%2B%2B

Answer (score 52):

I really can't believe I'm reviewing [lolcode](/questions/tagged/lolcode) right now...

- The specification does allow for variables to be any case, but all existing documentation uses lower case for variables. So, lowercase variables would be more idiomatic, but I'd go with camelCase for readability.
- `Frootloopz` is creative and idiomatic, but `Froot` is meaningless beyond its relation to `Frootloopz`. `Loopz` would still be idiomatic and `counter` would be more meaningful.
- [As @Pimgd noted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/61429/41243), you can reduce the nesting by putting `O RLY?, YA RLY` on a single line.
- The code both calculates and prints. LOLCODE supports functions. I would use it to separate the concerns. Particularly since this is an exercise in learning the language.

> A function is demarked with the opening keyword `HOW IZ I` and the closing keyword `IF U SAY SO`. The syntax is as follows:

> ```
> HOW IZ I <function name> [YR <argument1> [AN YR <argument2> …]]
> ```

```
     <code block>
IF U SAY SO
```

Answer (score 33):

### Indentation

You've gone with a structure like this:

```
O RLY?
    YA RLY
        Froot R "Buzz"
OIC
```

I don't really like it. It has an extra indentation level. Instead, I'd opt to do this:

```
O RLY?, YA RLY
    Froot R "Buzz"
OIC
```

You do get multiple statements on one line, but I'd see the `IZ WIN` (`== true` for those who are LOLCODE-inexperienced) as a part of the if statement.

### Indentation - Comments

```
  I HAS A Froot ITZ SUM OF Frootz AN 1
    BTW Froot will run 1 through 100
```

Why is this comment indented? I think it should be like so

```
  I HAS A Froot ITZ SUM OF Frootz AN 1
  BTW Froot will run 1 through 100
```

Because there's no indentation level by variable assignment.

### Magic numbers

`100` should be a constant with a name that describes its meaning. Something like `FIZZBUZZLIMIT` or `MAXFIZZBUZZNUMBR`. Or even `STAHP`... but that might be less descriptive than the other names.

Comment: What else would you call the number 100? `HUN`?

Comment: @RubberDuck Limit, MaxLines, Amount... It's not about the value, it's about the context. That 100 could be 1000 or 250 or 1337. When do you want FizzBuzz to stop?

Comment: Just making sure you weren't suggesting this. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/44047/41243

Comment: I would humbly suggest the variable name `STAHP`