# Cheese-Burger-Waffles (aka Rock-Paper-Scissors)

Tags: game, rock-paper-scissors, lolcode

[FizzBuzz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/61416/23788) was fun, and I got great feedback and learned a few things (which I hope I put in practice here), but only scratched the surface. I wanted to explore the LOLCODE language a bit more, so I implemented a little *rock-paper-scissors*, to play with functions, parameters, return values.. and user input.

Unfortunately I haven't figured out how to get [compileonline](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_lolcode_online.php) to take more than a single value through STDIN, so I dropped the idea of making a `GAEMLOOPZ` and only made it a single round.

Also AFAICT there's no way of generating random numbers in LOLCODE ([specs](http://lolcode.org/1.2_spec.html)), so the LOLCAT always wins - it even has a *seekrit* move for invalid inputs!

```
HAI 1.2
  
  I HAS A CHEEZ ITZ "CHEEZ"       BTW "ROCK"
  I HAS A BURGR ITZ "BURGR"       BTW "PAPER"
  I HAS A WAFLZ ITZ "WAFLZ"       BTW "SCISSORS"
  I HAS A SEEKRITMOOV ITZ "ZPOCK" BTW SHH, SEEKRIT
  
  
  HOW IZ I GETAMOOV
    
    VISIBLE "WHAT U PLAY?"
    VISIBLE "[C]HEEZ [B]URGR [W]AFLZ"
    
    I HAS A MOOV
    GIMMEH MOOV
    
    MOOV R I IZ VALID8MOOV YR MOOV MKAY
    FOUND YR MOOV
    
  IF U SAY SO
  
  HOW IZ I VALID8MOOV YR MOOV
    
    MOOV, WTF?
      OMG "C", OMG "c"
        MOOV R CHEEZ
        GTFO
        
      OMG "B", OMG "b"
        MOOV R BURGR
        GTFO
      
      OMG "W", OMG "w"
        MOOV R WAFLZ
        GTFO
      
      OMGWTF
        ANY OF BOTH SAEM MOOV AN "ZPOCK" AN BOTH SAEM MOOV AN "zpock" MKAY
        O RLY?
          YA RLY, MOOV R SEEKRITMOOV
          NO WAI
            MOOV R SMOOSH "... WUTS " AN MOOV AN " ANYWAI" MKAY
        OIC

    OIC
    
    FOUND YR MOOV
    
  IF U SAY SO
  
  HOW IZ I PIKAMOOV YR MOOV

    I HAS A ULTIMAETMOOV
    
    MOOV, WTF?
      OMG "CHEEZ" BTW must be a constant value :(
        ULTIMAETMOOV R BURGR
        GTFO
        
      OMG "BURGR" BTW must be a constant value :(
        ULTIMAETMOOV R WAFLZ
        GTFO
      
      OMG "WAFLZ" BTW must be a constant value :(
        ULTIMAETMOOV R CHEEZ
        GTFO
      
      OMG "ZPOCK" BTW must be a constant value :(
        ULTIMAETMOOV R "Y U CHEAT? I"
        GTFO
      
      OMGWTF
        ULTIMAETMOOV R SEEKRITMOOV

    OIC
    
    FOUND YR ULTIMAETMOOV
    
  IF U SAY SO
  
  HOW IZ I WINTEHGAEM YR MOOV AN YR ULTIMAETMOOV
    
    VISIBLE SMOOSH "Y U PLAY " AN MOOV MKAY
    VISIBLE SMOOSH "MAH " AN ULTIMAETMOOV AN " WINZ LOL" MKAY
    
  IF U SAY SO
  
  OBTW      
    was going to make a GAEMLOOP,
    but stupidly I can't seem to figure out
    how to pass multiple values to STDIN with this "IDE"...
    so this program will only run a single round.
  TLDR
  
  HOW IZ I PLAYAMOOV
    
    I HAS A MOOV
    MOOV R I IZ GETAMOOV MKAY
    
    I HAS A ULTIMAETMOOV
    ULTIMAETMOOV R I IZ PIKAMOOV YR MOOV MKAY
    
    I IZ WINTEHGAEM YR MOOV AN YR ULTIMAETMOOV MKAY
    
  IF U SAY SO
  
  VISIBLE "CHEEZ-BURGR-WAFLZ:)"
  I IZ PLAYAMOOV MKAY

KTHXBYE
```

---

#### Outputs

Input: `c` or `C`

> ```
> CHEEZ-BURGR-WAFLZ
>
> WHAT U PLAY?
> [C]HEEZ [B]URGR [W]AFLZ
> Y U PLAY CHEEZ
> MAH BURGR WINZ LOL
> ```

Input: `b` or `B`

> ```
> CHEEZ-BURGR-WAFLZ
>
> WHAT U PLAY?
> [C]HEEZ [B]URGR [W]AFLZ
> Y U PLAY BURGR
> MAH WAFLZ WINZ LOL
> ```

Input: `w` or `W`

> ```
> CHEEZ-BURGR-WAFLZ
>
> WHAT U PLAY?
> [C]HEEZ [B]URGR [W]AFLZ
> Y U PLAY WAFLZ
> MAH CHEEZ WINZ LOL
> ```

Input: `zzz` ..or pretty much anything else:

> ```
> CHEEZ-BURGR-WAFLZ
>
> WHAT U PLAY?
> [C]HEEZ [B]URGR [W]AFLZ
> Y U PLAY ... WUTS zzz ANYWAI
> MAH ZPOCK WINZ LOL
> ```

Input: `zpock` or `ZPOCK`

> ```
> CHEEZ-BURGR-WAFLZ
>
> WHAT U PLAY?
> [C]HEEZ [B]URGR [W]AFLZ
> Y U PLAY ZPOCK
> MAH Y U CHEAT? I WINZ LOL
> ```

---

I don't like that I'm hard-coding the strings in the `WTF` (switch) block in `VALID8MOOV`, but I don't think it's possible to extract just the first letter of a `YARN` (string)... or is it? Also there doesn't seem to be a way of defining compile-time constants, so I had to put literal strings in `PIKAMOOV` as well.

Comment: specs link is broken btw

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
HAI 1.2

    I HAZ A REVIEW ITZ "Following" BTW Let's roll ;)
```

I got a few points I want to make here and the first is actually quite simple. Don't name your names in `INTORN3TZP34KZ`...

Yes I know it's an esoteric language, and I know that all the instructions are defined to be "Internet-Speaks". But that doesn't mean you absolutely have to make your code follow the spec definitions.
(Who makes their Stack a class anyway..)

`CHEEZ`, `BURGR`, `WAFLZ`, `SEEKRITMOOV`, ... these names are *suboptimal*. (Pardon my non-french).

You had it [pointed out to you](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/61445/37660) in [your previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/61416/37660), that the documentation uses lowercase for variables. (Seems the specs changed that...)
I think you should adopt either that or at least anything
**but** SHOUTCASE! There is no need to give a darn about convention when convention is dumb ;)

Especially with the missing syntax highlighting it is hard to read your code and differentiate between instructions and identifiers.

Additionally to that I want to suggest using non-speakzified variable names. Simply because it's easier on the brain to not have to unwrap the variable name before being allowed to think about what the variable name means in the first place.

### Moving swiftly on from names to... names..

`PIKAMOVE` - Is it just me or does that call associations with Pokémon to your head??
`VALID8MOOV` - What's the 8 anyways???

The names you chose are confusing. *Might* (wink wink) be because you actually made them Internetspeakz again :(

### Next!

### Whitespace / Newlines

> ```
>     OIC
>
>     FOUND YR ULTIMAETMOOV
>
>   IF U SAY SO
>
>   HOW IZ I WINTEHGAEM YR MOOV AN YR ULTIMAETMOOV
> ```

let's see how you'd put braces in Java (or C# for that matter) for this code:

```
    }
    return ultimateMoov;
}

void winthegaem (Object moov, Object ultimatemoov) {
```

You might want to additionally differentiate the "difference" between `IF YOU SAY SO` and `HOW IZ I`. I'd either add an additional newline between these or remove them on "closing the braces".

### Comments

> ```
>   OBTW      
>     was going to make a GAEMLOOP,
>     but stupidly I can't seem to figure out
>     how to pass multiple values to STDIN with this "IDE"...
>     so this program will only run a single round.
>   TLDR
> ```

Hmm.. Interesting. But **completely irrelevant for the code** This comment is not helping. You *did* mention it in your explanation, so in the code it's meaningless.

Reading the code does not become easier with reading this comment. Remove it.

### OMGWTF

Y U NO?

```
    OMG "ZPOCK", OMG "zpock"
        MOOV R SEEKRITMOOV
        GTFO

    OMGWTF
        MOOV R SMOOSH "... WUTS " AN MOOV AN " ANYWAI" MKAY
  OIC
```

### KTHXBYE

BTW End of review ;)

Comment: TLDR Just Voted, JK LOL.